# SQL Server 2017 - Bulk Insert SQLBIT type using format file and FORMAT = CSV parameter

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have an input CSV file. Data in CSV is enclosed in the text qualifier (double quotes) So for bulk insert to remove double quotes while inserting to table, I am using FORMAT = 'CSV' parameter.

One of the column in CSV contains Boolean data (TRUE/FALSE) and I want it to be inserted in SQL table **(SQL 2017)** as 1 and 0 with its datatype as bit. So in the format file, I have specified its type as SQLBIT and for others SQLCHAR.

But Bulk Insert fails with **Error:**

```
Cannot bulk load CSV file. Invalid field parameters are specified for source column number 3 in the format file. All data fields must be either character or Unicode character with terminator when CSV format is specified.
```

From the above error one thing I understood is that when I am using FORMAT = 'CSV' parameter, I cannot use SQLBIT in format file. With SQLCHAR its working but then in SQL table I have to change datatype to varchar(5)  instead of bit which I don't want.

So is there a way wherein I can use both SQLBIT in format file while using FORMAT = 'CSV' parameter OR if not SQLBIT then any other workaorund to insert values in SQL table as 1 & 0 without changing datype?

**Input CSV:**

```
Id,Address,IsActive,CreatedDate
"I1","NY,U.S.","TRUE","2020-01-01"
"I2","Perth,Aus","FALSE","2020-02-01"
```

**SQL TABLE:**

```
Create table dbo.Bulk_Fmt_Test
(
   Id char(2) not null,
   Address varchar(255),
   IsActive bit,
  CreatedDate datetime2
)
```

**Format File:**

```
14.0
4
1 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "," 1 Id ""
2 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "," 2 Address ""
3 SQLBIT  0  1   "," 3 IsActive ""
4 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "\n" 4 CreatedDate ""
```

**Bulk Insert Query:**

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Bulk_Fmt_Test from 'C:\Data\Sample1.csv'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2, FormatFile = 'C:\Data\Sample.fmt');
```

Comment: you're probably going to have to use a staging table.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert to temporary table firstly, then validate it and insert to your table. Thus you can insert without you get an error.

```
CREATE TABLE #Bulk_Fmt_Test(
   Id varchar(100),
   Address varchar(300),
   IsActive varchar(10),
   CreatedDate varchar(20)
)

BULK INSERT #Bulk_Fmt_Test from 'C:\Data\Sample1.csv'
WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2, FormatFile ='C:\Data\Sample.fmt');

INSERT INTO Bulk_Fmt_Test (Id, Address, IsActive, CreatedDate)
SELECT
TRY_CONVERT(char(2), Id),
LEFT(Address, 255),
ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(bit, IsActive), IIF(IsActive = 'TRUE', 1, 0)),
TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, CreatedDate)
FROM #Bulk_Fmt_Test
```

Note: TRY_CONVERT is a reserved keyword in compatibility level 110 and higher.
Detailed information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1):

The format file describes the file format rather than the table. The strings "TRUE" and "FALSE" are character data, not a binary bit value that a `SQLBIT` format specification indicates. These Boolean string values can be implicitly converted to bit in T-SQL but `BULK INSERT` (and `BCP`) does not do that.

As a workaround, specify `SQLCHAR` in the format file and use `INSERT … FROM OPENROWSET … BULK` to convert the Boolean values implicitly. I tested the example below with Windows CR/LF row terminators instead of only LF as in your question but I expect you'll get the desired results with LF too:

```
14.0
4
1 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "," 1 Id ""
2 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "," 2 Address ""
3 SQLCHAR 0 5    "," 3 IsActive ""
4 SQLCHAR 0 9999 "\r\n" 4 CreatedDate ""
```

T-SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Bulk_Fmt_Test(Id, Address, IsActive, CreatedDate)
SELECT Id, Address, IsActive, CreatedDate
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Data\Sample1.csv',
    FORMATFILE = N'C:\Data\Sample.fmt',
    FIRSTROW=2,
    FORMAT='CSV') AS source;
```